# Where to place the __declspec(dllimport) keyword when declaring types with using (c++11)

Tags: c++, c++11

I usually see the C++11 keyword `using` as a type declaration.

I want to make that type visible for the users of my shared library (dll).

So (for windows) I export it with `__declspec(dllimport)`.

```
__declspec(dllimport) using History = std::list<Event>; //this code is wrong
```

But I don't know where to put it. I get only errors.

Comment: I found my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440948/4824854

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110833/dynamically-importing-a-c-class-from-a-dll

Answer (score 1):

`__declspec(dllimport)` is not a part of a type, so you cannot put it in `using` declaration.

A customary way is: `#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)` and put `IMPORT` in front of each function prototype. It is also possible to use conditional compilation to define `IMPORT` as `__declspec(dllexport)` inside the DLL.

Comment: My mistake, I replaced a macro with the wrong content. I do the adjustment.

Comment: I have the macro you mentioned. I just dropped it in my code example.